# getId() method of Entity generates label collisions in DAO_Impl

Tags: android, dao

I have noticed no understandable error of generated implementation for my DAO, when using Android Room. First of all I need to mention that I'm making my app as a modification of [Android Room with a View](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0).

I have a class for Task:

app/java/com.example.blah/Task.java:

```
package ...

import ...

@Entity
public class Task {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    protected int _id;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    protected String _description;

    public Task(@NonNull String description) {
        _description = description;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {return _description;}
}
```

When I try to build this code I'm getting compilation error from one of the generated classes:

app/**generatedJava**/com.example.blah/TaskDAO_Impl.java
    package ...

```
import ...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class TaskDAO_Impl implements TaskDAO {
  private final RoomDatabase __db;

  private final EntityInsertionAdapter __insertionAdapterOfTask;

  private final SharedSQLiteStatement __preparedStmtOfDeleteAll;

  public TaskDAO_Impl(RoomDatabase __db) {
    this.__db = __db;
    this.__insertionAdapterOfTask = new EntityInsertionAdapter<Task>(__db) {
      @Override
      public String createQuery() {
        return "INSERT OR ABORT INTO `Task`(`id`,`description`) VALUES (nullif(?, 0),?)";
      }

      @Override
      public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, Task value) {
        stmt.bindLong(1, value.getId());
        if (value.getDescription() == null) {
          stmt.bindNull(2);
        } else {
          stmt.bindString(2, value.getDescription());
        }
      }
    };
    this.__preparedStmtOfDeleteAll = new SharedSQLiteStatement(__db) {
      @Override
      public String createQuery() {
        final String _query = "DELETE FROM Task";
        return _query;
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void insert(Task task) {
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      __insertionAdapterOfTask.insert(task);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void deleteAll() {
    final SupportSQLiteStatement _stmt = __preparedStmtOfDeleteAll.acquire();
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      _stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
      __preparedStmtOfDeleteAll.release(_stmt);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasks() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM Task ORDER BY description ASC";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    return new ComputableLiveData<List<Task>>() {
      private Observer _observer;

      @Override
      protected List<Task> compute() {
        if (_observer == null) {
          _observer = new Observer("Task") {
            @Override
            public void onInvalidated(@NonNull Set<String> tables) {
              invalidate();
            }
          };
          __db.getInvalidationTracker().addWeakObserver(_observer);
        }
        final Cursor _cursor = __db.query(_statement);
        try {
          final int _cursorIndexOfId = _cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id");
          final int _cursorIndexOfDescription = _cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description");
          final List<Task> _result = new ArrayList<Task>(_cursor.getCount());
          while(_cursor.moveToNext()) {
            final Task _item;
            final String _tmp_description;
            _tmp_description = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfDescription);
            _item.getId = _cursor.getInt(_cursorIndexOfId);
            final String _tmp_1;
            _tmp_1 = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfActivationDate);
            _item._activationDate = DateStringConverter.intoDate(_tmp_1);
            _item.points = _cursor.getInt(_cursorIndexOfPoints);
            _result.add(_item);
          }
          return _result;
        } finally {
          _cursor.close();
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected void finalize() {
        _statement.release();
      }
    }.getLiveData();
  }
}
```

And this line:

```
_item.getId = _cursor.getInt(_cursorIndexOfId);
```

Is causing the error:

> error: cannot find symbol variable getId

because there is no field getId in class Task. Please note that class mentioned above is not written by me. It's automatically generated by Android Studio.

I wonder why this happen? If I delete function getId() from Task class, everything becomes all right. For the generated code mentioned above, once I delete getId() function, the suspicious line turns into:

```
_item._id = _cursor.getInt(_cursorIndexOfId);
```

And everything compiles all right. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `int getId;` variable in your `Task` class.. This is unusual situation..Maybe it is `Room Persistence Library`'s bug..

> Perhaps this method is not true way to solve the problem but it works
>   at least.